# Select and unselect component when one is selected

Tags: react-native, use-state, touchableopacity

I've to display three components (cards) from which the user can select one. I've placed those three components inside a `ScrollView` as:

```
...
            <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <LocationAndPriceCard
                    price={'100'}
                    title={'Choice 3'} />
                <LocationAndPriceCard
                    price={'200'}
                    title={'Choice 2'} />
                <LocationAndPriceCard
                    price={'300'}
                    title={'Choice 1'}} />
            </ScrollView>
...
```

Here is how `LocationAndPriceCard` is coded:

```
...
function LocationAndPriceCard({ price, title }) {

    const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState("red")

    const styles = getStyles(selectedLocation);

    const selected = () => {
        if (selectedLocation == "red") {
            setSelectedLocation("green")
        } else {
            setSelectedLocation("red")
        }
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.frame} onPress={selected}>

            <Text style={styles.priceTxt}>RM {price}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2}>{title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

const getStyles = (borderC) => StyleSheet.create({
    frame: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: borderC,
        width: 180,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 8,
        margin: 5,
        padding: 10,
    },
...
```

In the code above when the cad has selected it successfully change the border color to `green` but I can change the color of all the components. I want to make it like if one is selected all others should go back to `red` color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create two new props for `LocationAndPriceCard`, `value` and `onPress`.

Use `value` to determine which card is selected and based on that change the border color.

Use the `onPress` function to set the state which will have the `title` of the selected card, which we will be used to determine which card is selected.

**Full Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/trembling-bubblegum)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const handleSelected = (value) => {
    setSelected(value);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <LocationAndPriceCard
          price={'100'}
          title={'Choice 3'}
          onPress={handleSelected}
          value={selected}
        />
        <LocationAndPriceCard
          price={'200'}
          title={'Choice 2'}
          onPress={handleSelected}
          value={selected}
        />
        <LocationAndPriceCard
          price={'300'}
          title={'Choice 1'}
          onPress={handleSelected}
          value={selected}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

function LocationAndPriceCard({ price, title, onPress, value }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[styles.frame, { borderColor: value === title?"green":"red" }]}
      onPress={()=>onPress(title)}>
      <Text style={styles.priceTxt}>RM {price}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={2}>
        {title}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  frame: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 8,
    margin: 5,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```